# Controlling multiple banks of LED bulbs with one dimmer switch

Tags: electrical, led, recessed-lighting, dimmer-switch

Just had the contractor install some recessed LED lighting in some of the rooms of the house. Due to building codes we can't have one location with enough switches to control the lights as we have them set up, at least in the living room anyhow.

There are 3 rows of lights. I'd like to be able to dim each row independently. The contractor who did the wiring doesn't seem to up on the more high end dimmer switches, and the electrician who's going to wire everything into the panel isn't due to show up for a few more days.

So i'd like to know what my options are now before they finish all the wiring and install the switches.

I looked at some of the LED dimmer switches from Lutron and they have some called single pole/multi location. Does this mean the one switch can control more then one bank of lights? Other than purchasing the switch itself, is there anything else that needs to be purchased/installed?

Is there some other brand I should look at as far as one switch controlling multiple banks of dimmable LEDs?

Appreciate any advice in this area. Thanks

Comment: Where abouts do you live? In my are there are a number of professional lighting design groups who'd give you the information you need.

Comment: I'm in the San Francisco area. I'm not looking to hire a lighting designer for this though. I just want to know if these switches will allow me to control more than one light and if so, is there additional equipment that has to be wired in for that to work.